# what does "::" mean in kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm new to Kotlin
I used this code for opening another activity:

```
startActivity(Intent(this,IntroAndLang::class.java))
```

current activity and target activity are written in Kotlin

I can't understand why there is not single `:` instead of `::` at `IntroAndLang::class.java`

Comment: : is for declaration, :: is an operator. See [here](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/reflection.html).

Comment: @m0skit0 thanks,why its class.java when I'm using a kotlin class?

Comment: Android API only accepts Java classes, that's why you need to pass a Java class. `IntroAndLang::class` returns a `KClass` (a Kotlin class), then `.java` returns the Java class. Note that all Kotlin classes are compiled to Java classes (`.class` binaries) in the end.

Answer (score 134, accepted):

`::` is used for Reflection in kotlin

1. Class Reference `val myClass = MyClass::class`
2. Function Reference `this::isEmpty`, `::isOdd`
3. Property Reference `::someVal.isInitialized`
4. Constructor Reference `::MyClass`

For detailed reading [Official Documentation](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/reflection.html)

Comment: the best answer by far

Comment: @mohsen agreed.

Comment: I was wondering why `isInitialized ` works only with `::` operator, but after that I found this answer and now I know why. `::` operator get a reference to the property. Thanks @Rahul Sharma

Comment: Do method and property references qualify as reflection?

Answer (score 114):

**:: converts  a Kotlin function into a lambda.**

Let's say you have a function that looks like this:

```
fun printSquare(a: Int) = println(a * 2)
```

And you have a class that takes a lambda as a 2nd argument:

```
class MyClass(var someOtherVar: Any, var printSquare: (Int) -> Unit) {
        
    fun doTheSquare(i: Int) {
        printSquare(i)
    }
}
```

How do you pass the `printSquare` function into `MyClass`? If you try the following, it wont work:

```
  MyClass("someObject", printSquare) //printSquare is not a LAMBDA, it's a function so it gives compile error of wrong argument
```

So how do we CONVERT printSquare into a lambda so we can pass it around? Use the `::` notation.

```
MyClass("someObject",::printSquare) //now compiler does not complain since it's expecting a lambda and we have indeed converted the `printSquare` FUNCTION into a LAMBDA.
```

Also, please note that `this` is implied...  meaning `this::printSquare` is the same as `::printSquare`. So if the `printSquare` function was in another class, like a Presenter, then you could convert it to lambda like this:

```
Presenter::printSquare
```

UPDATE:

Also this works with constructors.  If you want to create the constructor of a class and then convert it to a lambda, it is done like this:

```
(x, y) -> MyClass::new
```

this translates to `MyClass(x, y)` in Kotlin.

Comment: are you sure `MyObject::new` still works?  I get an error when including it in source code as an expression.

Comment: I don't quite agree with the wording of this answer, as in the context of programming languages "lambda" (usually) refers to _anonymous_ function. On the other hand, the `::` operator (in this context) creates a _callable reference_ to a function, i.e. a name that can be used to call said function later in the code.

Answer (score 52):

As stated in the [docs](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/reflection.html#class-references) this is a **class reference**:

> Class References:
>   The most basic reflection feature is getting the **runtime reference** to a Kotlin class. To obtain the reference to a statically known Kotlin class, you can use the class literal syntax:

```
val c = MyClass::class
//The reference is a value of type KClass.
```

> Note that a Kotlin class reference is not the same as a Java class reference. *To obtain a Java class reference, use the .java property on a KClass instance.*

It’s **also** the syntax for method references as in this simple example:

```
list.forEach(::println)
```

It refers to `println` defined in Kotlin Standard library.

Comment: `::println` and `IntroAndLang::class` are unrelated despite both using `::`. Method reference couldn't evaluate to a `KClass`, it isn't a SAM type!

Comment: You’re right that was not the cleanest answer, I modified it

Comment: :: is just a way to write a lambda expression basically we can use this to refer to a method i.e a member function or property
 for example 
```class Person (val name: String, val age: Int)```
Now we can write this to access the person which has the maximium age. ```people.maxBy{it.age}```
we can modify the above to 
```people.maxBy(Person::age)```

Answer (score 3):

Since kotlin 1.1, in addition to class, function, property and constructor references as stated above,    '::' can also be used to obtain the bound references to all of the above.

For instance, using '::class' could be used to get the exact class of a particular object despite the type of the receiver as below...

```
val widget: Widget = ...
assert(widget is GoodWidget) { "Bad widget: ${widget::class.qualifiedName}" }
```

widget::class returns the exact class of the object 'widget' as either 'GoodWidget' or 'BadWidget' despite the type of the receiver expression (i.e 'Widget' as declared initially)

More info at https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/reflection.html