# What does this "::" mean in kotlin when used in this context?

Tags: kotlin

I´m following the Udacity course to learn how to develop android apps, and I don´t understand the following piece of code:

```
 private val night = MediatorLiveData<SleepNight>()
    fun getNight() = night

    init {
        night.addSource(database.getNightWithId(sleepNightKey), night::setValue)
    }
```

Specifically, I don´t understand the "::" part, from some answers to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47400942/what-does-mean-in-kotlin/52463397) question I know that is used to transform a function into a lambda, I also checked the [official docs](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/keyword-reference.html) and says that is used to create a member reference and a class reference, I think in this case it is used to create a member reference but I don´t clearly see how that works in this case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this context it is `bound function reference` - see https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reflection.html#bound-function-and-property-references for details.

It basically means a reference to a method `setValue` but called on the object `night` (night is its receiver).

`night::setValue` <=> `{ night.setValue() }`