# Why do we use ::class.java in Kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin

Why do we have to use `::class.java` for referencing a class while creating Android apps in Kotlin? Despite the fact that the referenced class is in Kotlin.

As an example, if we want to Start an activity from another activity we have to use `Intent(this, sampleActivity::class.java)` to initiate an Intent.

Note: My query does not refer to the distinction between (:) single colon and (::) double colon, which is addressed [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47400942/what-does-mean-in-kotlin). I'm curious. Why is 'class.java' used in a Kotlin class?

Comment: fyi, for Android Kotlin is compiled to Java byte-code just like Java. You might be interested in reading this: https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/process-compiling-android-app-javakotlin-code-ban-markovic/

Answer (score 0):

Because its signature accepts `Class<?>` and `Intent` itelf is written in Java.